# where does $k$ lie?

Tags: real-analysis

if $f(x) = -1 + kx  + k$ neither touches nor intercepts the curve $g(x)= \log x$,then the  minimum value $k \in ? $

choose the correct option

a)$\left( \frac{1}{e}, \frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{2} }\right)$

b) $\left(e,e^2\right)$

c) $\left(\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{2} },e\right)$

d) none of these

I was trying that  $f'(x) = k$  and $k= \log x$  after that I get $x = e^k$

now here I can conclude that option b is correct answer

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: i have mention it @Arthur

Comment: @Stupid maybe is better to clarify that  the value for the tangency condition fall in a) but the correct solution is d) since we are looking for a "minimum". The value for k for tangency condition is indeed an infimum and it can be easily shown by contradiction or by a different approach (see solution from egreg).

Comment: @Stupid why did you chose this nickname! It's very stupid! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Look for the value of k for the tangency condition.

Comment: im not getting @ gimusi    can u elaboarte more ???

Comment: @Stupid set equal the derivatives of the two functions, in your attempt you didn't derive $\log x$

Comment: ok @Gimusi  here i get  - log x= log k  and  $x = - e^{logk}  $  after that  i can 't able to proceed further ??

Comment: @Stupid how did you get that? note that $f'(x)=k$ and $g'(x)=1/x$

Comment: i get its  ...that value   after that i take log boths sides

Comment: k= 1/x   and after that taking log both sides

Comment: @Stupid now for the tangency we need also f(x)=g(x)

Comment: @Stupid did you obtain the final condition on k?

Comment: i don't  know    actually  i just assume ......if u know the answer  pliz elaborate ur answer more >>>>

Comment: @Stupid we have obtained $x=1/k$, now set $f(1/k)=g(1/k)$ what condition we obtain on $k$?

Comment: ok here i got k = log(1/k) and$ k = \frac{1}{e^k}$

Comment: @Stupid For the solution of $ke^k=1$ refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant

Comment: thanks a lots @gimusi   ,,for  ur valuable time

Comment: @Stupid You are welcome! and solved by yoursef with only a guide, thats good! Bye

Answer (score 0):

If you set $h(x)=kx+k-1-\log x$, the problem is to identify when the equation $h(x)=0$ has no solution.

By looking at limits at $0$ and $\infty$, we immediately disqualify $k\le0$, so we can assume $k>0$. Since $h'(x)=(kx-1)/x$, the function has an absolute minimum at $1/k$, where
$$
h(1/k)=k+\log k
$$
The equation $h(x)=0$ has no solution when $k+\log k>0$. Consider $\gamma(t)=t+\log t$. Then $\gamma'(t)=(t+1)/t$ is positive and there exists $k_0$ such that $\gamma(t)>0$ if and only $t>k_0$. Since $\gamma(e^{-1})=e^{-1}-1<0$ and $\gamma(e^{-1/2})=e^{-1/2}-1/2>0$, we know that $k_0\in(e^{-1},e^{-1/2})$.

The equation $h(x)=0$ has no solution if and only if $k>k_0$. However for $k=k_0$, the equation $h(x)=0$ has a solution. The correct option is (d), because there is no minimum.

Just for completeness, $e>1$ entails $e^{-1}<1$; $e<4$ entails $e^{1/2}<2$, so $e^{-1/2}>1/2$.

The value $k_0$ is where the line $f(x)=kx+k-1$ and the curve $g(x)=\log x$ touch each other. The problem states “neither touches nor intercepts”, so $k_0$ must be discarded.

Comment: sorry It seems that there exists a value for the tangency condition, I will revise my reasoning about it. Thanks

Comment: @gimusi “neither touches nor intercepts” seems quite clear, doesn't it?

Comment: yes of course, my idea was to find the  unique solution for tangency and then take a value slightly different, of course that value is a infimum not a minimum, is it correct?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, $k_0$ (for which there is tangency) is the infimum of the values $k$ so there is no intersection.

Comment: ah ok, then once I’ve shown that the solution for tangency is unique I can conclude suddenly that we have not minimum

Comment: @gimusi I would not accept such a leap without a proper analysis.

Comment: we know that exists unique $a$ such that $h(a)=0$ ,suppose exists   $b>a$ minimum such that $h(b)\neq 0$ then we can chose $c=(b+a)/2$ and $h(b)\neq 0$

Comment: correction "...and $h(c)\neq 0$". Does it suffice?